# How can i grab a url string (node, mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a application where when a user created a account, they will be directed to their only profile setting page. The url looks like this http://localhost:5000/users/setting/5ea60977c4ef642b9d4c1ea9
on that page, there is another form the users need to submit so my question is, what will be the action on that form? it cannot be "action: 'users/setting'" since the url is dynamic.
I need to have the Objectid to update the specific users data so I am assuming I need to somehow grab the users id from the url.

so far I have:

```
router.post("/setting/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log (req.params.id)
  const {educaiton, religion, language} = req.body
  User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: {education: req.body.education, Religon: req.body.Religon, language: req.body.language}}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log ('bad')
    } else {
      console.log ('good')
    }
  })

});
```

my ejs form :

```
 <form class="info" action="/users/setting/" method="POST">
        <div class="fields">


            <div class="education">
                <label for="education">Education</label>
                <select name="education" id="education">
                    <option value="bachelor">bachelor</option>
                    <option value="Master">Master</option>
                    <option value="Phd">Phd</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
</form
```

Answer (score 0):

try to concatenate the settings directory with the user id
url: 'users/setting' + user_id